# Make Nodejs script run in background in gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, background, continuous-integration, gitlab

Our dev project start by command `npm run serve` Is it possible to run it on background mode? I tried to use nohup, & in end of string. It works properly in shell, but when it start by CI on Gitlab, pipeline state always is "running" cause npm output permanently shows on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be to run a container whose run command is "npm run serve"

I'm not certain running a non-blocking command through your pipeline is the right way but you should try using "&"
"npm run serve" will run the command in  "detached mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem using `nohup and &`. It was working well in shell, but not on Gitlab CI, It looks like `npm start` was not detached.

What worked for me is to call `npm start` inside a bash script and run it on `before_script` hook.

```
test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - ./serverstart.sh
  script:
   - npm test
  after_script:
    - kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '\snode\s' | awk '{print $2}')
```

on the bash script `serverstart.sh`

```sh
# !/bin/bash

# start the server and send the console and error logs on nodeserver.log
npm start > nodeserver.log 2>&1 &

# keep waiting until the server is started 
# (in my case wait for mongodb://localhost:27017/app-test to be logged)
while ! grep -q "mongodb://localhost:27017/app-test" nodeserver.log
do
  sleep .1
done
echo -e "server has started\n"
exit 0
```

this allowed me to detach `npm start` and pass to next command while keeping `npm start`process alive